# boost test and visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013

Tried a simple test with `boost::test` on visual studio 2013:

```
#define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc120"
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(1 == 2);
}
```

After building, when run, this fails with the following stack trace. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Error : **`Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`**

```
>   OrderProxy.exe!std::list<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter>,std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter> > >::begin() Line 1121  C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::for_each::begin<std::list<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter>,std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter> > > >(const std::list<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter>,std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::runtime::cla::parameter> > > & t, boost::mpl::bool_<1> __formal) Line 107 C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::runtime::cla::parser::operator[](boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const > string_id) Line 169 C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::runtime_config::`anonymous namespace'::retrieve_parameter<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const > parameter_name, const boost::runtime::cla::parser & s_cla_parser, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & default_value, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & optional_value) Line 216  C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::runtime_config::report_sink() Line 470 C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::results_reporter::`anonymous namespace'::results_reporter_impl::results_reporter_impl() Line 59    C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::results_reporter::`anonymous namespace'::s_rr_impl() Line 91   C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::results_reporter::get_stream() Line 120    C++
    OrderProxy.exe!boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(boost::unit_test::test_suite * (int, char * *) * init_func, int argc, char * * argv) Line 207   C++
    OrderProxy.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 237   C++
    [External Code] 
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
```

Inside stack trace, jumps from here:

```
int BOOST_TEST_DECL
unit_test_main( init_unit_test_func init_func, int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    try {
        framework::init( init_func, argc, argv );

        if( !runtime_config::test_to_run().is_empty() ) {
            test_case_filter filter( runtime_config::test_to_run() );

            traverse_test_tree( framework::master_test_suite().p_id, filter );
        }

        framework::run();

        results_reporter::make_report();

        return runtime_config::no_result_code() 
                    ? boost::exit_success
                    : results_collector.results( framework::master_test_suite().p_id ).result_code();
    }
    catch( framework::nothing_to_test const& ) {
        return boost::exit_success;
    }
    catch( framework::internal_error const& ex ) {
        results_reporter::get_stream() << "Boost.Test framework internal error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;

        return boost::exit_exception_failure;
    }
    catch( framework::setup_error const& ex ) {
        results_reporter::get_stream() << "Test setup error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;

        return boost::exit_exception_failure;
    }
    catch( ... ) {
>>>>>>>>>>>> here >>>>>>>            results_reporter::get_stream() << "Boost.Test framework internal error: unknown reason" << std::endl;

        return boost::exit_exception_failure;
    }
}
```